# backbone.js change event only triggering the first once

Tags: backbone.js, model, event-binding

I've got a backbone.js model which contains a calendar. The user can go back and forth in the calendar and I can get the events for the selected calendar day.

In my Model, I have

```
initialize: function(){
    this.on('change:date',this.get_cal());
},
get_cal: function(){
    alert('get calendar');
    this.fetch(...
}
```

and in my view I have

```
 cal_date: function(move){
    Myapp.cal.attributes.date.setDate(Myapp.cal.attributes.date.getDate()+move);

}
```

when the date changes, I expected backbone to trigger the change event, and get the calendar events for the new date. Unfortunately, that isn't happening.

I've also tried putting the printed date into the model as

```
Myapp.cal.set({print_date: formatted_date});
```

thinking that maybe backbone is missing the update because I'm not calling 'set', or because it sees a date object and thinks that it already had a date object and therefore didn't change.

I've also tried to trigger the change with `Myapp.cal.trigger('change')`, in the view but that didn't work either. Nor did removing the calendar events by calling `Myapp.cal.cal_events.refresh()` where cal_events is the collection holding the days events.

Do you see what's wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the issue is with the parentheses after **get_call** on this line:

```
this.on('change:date',this.get_cal());
```

You should remove them because they call **get_call** right in initialize instead of making them an event handler.

Comment: that was right Ivan, any chance you can explain, or point me to something that explains the difference between calling the `this.get_cal()` function, and `this.get_cal` without the braces? I don't understand why one works, and the other doesn't.

Comment: @pedalpete With parentheses(this.get_call()), get_call will get executed right away. Without the parentheses(this.get_call), you are passing the function object which will be called later when the appropriate event occurs

Comment: @pedalpete function in JavaScript is a data type like string or integer. Without parentheses you pass function itself like an argument (that's what you usually want to do when you specify a callback), with parentheses - it's return value.